# Instance variable nil in one view, not in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project in Ruby on Rails (Ruby v.2.2.8, Rails 5.1.4) and have encountered a very strange issue.

For my show method in the controller, I have:

```
def show
    @county = County.find(params[:id])
end
```

And it works. For update, I have.

```
def update
    @county = County.find(params[:id])

    if @county.update(county_params)
        redirect_to @county
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

In my 'edit', I consistently get an error that @county is nil. The error page indicates that the parameters are being passed as:

```
{'id'=>4}
```

as an example. When I use find_by from the rails console, the item is found.

Is there something here I'm missing?

ETA: View Code

```
<%= form_with model: @county, local: true do |form| %>

    <% if @county.errors.any? %>
         <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2>
                  <%= pluralize(@county.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
    this county from being saved:
              </h2>
              <ul>
                <% @county.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
        </div>
   <% end %>
   <p>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :shortname %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :shortname %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

ETA Routes for Counties:

```
counties GET /counties(.:format) counties#index
         POST /counties(.:format) counties#create
new_county GET /counties/new(.:format) counties#new
edit_county GET /counties/:id/edit(.:format) counties#edit
county GET /counties/:id(.:format) counties#show
       PATCH /counties/:id(.:format) counties#update
       PUT /counties/:id(.:format) counties#update
       DELETE /counties/:id(.:format) counties#destroy
```

The error occurs at /counties/:id/edit

Comment: Show your view. Is it as simple as a typo? `@country` instead of `@county` or something?

Comment: Can you please share your `set_county` method of your county controller?

Comment: Added the view code. I do not have a `set_county` method in my controller.

Comment: Can you include the exact error that you're getting, verbatim?

Comment: Also, what are your routes relating to the Country model?

Comment: `Showing /home/rails4_syslib/rails4.gchrl.org/public/app/views/counties/_form.html.erb where line #3 raised:`

`undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your edit action in your controller?

You should define @county as well

```
def edit
  @county = County.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Not necessary if they are rendering `:edit` from update action.

Comment: Yes, but I understood that the form he showed is in edit action

Comment: Yeah, I know, maybe I was unclear. I mean, if he is rendering the edit view from edit action he may need to set the variable in its action

Comment: Yes, indeed. Although I did get the impression that it's not the case here. He should reveal edit action to remove ambiguity.

Comment: I'm rendering the edit view from the update action - there is no edit action in the controller.

Comment: @slink: there is a default, empty, action, which just renders the corresponding view (and doesn't set any variables). When does the error happen, when you open edit page?

Comment: It does. And as an experiment I inserted a defined edit action setting `@county = County.find(params[:id])` and received the same error when opening the edit page.

Comment: Scratch that - I had a typo in the edit action. Adding that solved the issue.

Comment: What happens if in your edit action you render params variable?

Comment: @Morris: so, you were right all along, and his descriptions were very misleading :)